# Inserting nodes into an existing XML document in GWT client using XMLParser

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I have an xml document (using the Document class in the XMLParser library of GWT client) with a format like follows:

```
<document><node id="0">content</node><node id="1">more content</node></document>
```

Given an ID, I need to insert a new node immediately after the node with that ID.

So far I've tried using [insertBefore](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Node.html#insertBefore%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node%29) (as there is no insertAfter), but I must be using it incorrectly as nothing happens (apart from an UmbrellaException in the js console). I can't find any example usage via search engines.

My attempt is as follows (where n is the node I want to insert after):

```
Node nNext = n.getNextSibling(); //To get the next sibling to use it with insertBefore
Element newNode = doc.createElement("node");
newNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("new content")); //seems to work up until here
n.insertBefore(newNode, nNext); //so this line could be the problem?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertBefore` must be called on the parent node, so:

```
n.getParentNode().insertBefore(newNode, n.getNextSibling());
```